# JDBC PostgreSQL check database for empty tables and delete them

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have to check for tables in PostgreSQL database that have empty rows, using JDBC, and then delete them from the server. How can I do that? I'm pretty convinced I'd have to iterate through ResultSet object I'd get from the "search" query and put the table names in a looped DROP statement, but have no idea how to retrieve them.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name getting count from database statisctics to perform drop table, I won't go that way

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2276644/330315

Answer (score 0):

check [List all tables in postgresql information_schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276644/list-all-tables-in-postgresql-information-schema)

in short `select * from information_schema.tables` shows all tables